# Understanding the difference between Async/Await and Task

Tags: python, asynchronous, async-await, task

In the Python documentation it describes how to start and use [`coroutines`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#coroutines).

This section describes how to use a [`Task`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-object).

In the `Task` section, it states:

> Tasks are used to schedule coroutines concurrently

I'm failing to understand, what is happening when I start a `coroutines` **without** using `Task`? Is the code running [asynchronously](https://stackoverflow.com/a/748189/10597450) but not **concurrently**? Does it mean when the code sees an `await` it goes and does something else?

When I use a `Task` is it **like** start two threads and calling `join()`? I start two or more tasks and wait for the result, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple cases, creating `Tasks` manually is somewhat similar to threads – you can create them, event loop will eventually run them, and you should eventually get result/exception.

But in most cases, your code is built around `await coro()` – nothing low-level. This means that your code *may* do some I/O operation inside `coro`, so process is free to put your implicitly created task into queue, and resume execution later.